# Use both antennas, Intel Dual Band Wireless - AC 7260 [7260HMW]

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver, dual-band

I just got the following wifi adapter:
Intel Dual Band Wireless - AC 7260 [7260HMW]
https://amzn.com/B00HJCBV64

It has inputs for two antennas, but no matter what I do the second input does not work.
Only input 1 seems to be working. When I take the same antenna to input 2 almost nothing happens. I only see one of the many surrounding access points, but the signal is so weak I can not even load a website. I remember reading that second input might need to be enabled by software/driver, but the provided software does not have any settings associated with that.

How do I get input 2 to work?

Answer (score 1):

One wire is for Wi-Fi and the other is for Bluetooth. I take it you bought this Wi-Fi card as replacement for an existing Wi-Fi/BT card. Therefore you just screw the White and black wires the same it was on the old card. There are YouTube tutorials and Google images on these wires.

Bluetooth didn't work straightaway in my case. There is a pin (number 51 I think) that you need to tape over for BT to work. Again this is covered in many tutorials concerning this Wi-Fi card. What happens is your laptop is sending an off signal to the card on certain pin(s). To prevent this, you cut a very thin strip of tape and apply it on that tiny pin connector. Then the card will power on its radios.

Please do some research. Follow the tutorial to the letter, so you know which is Pin 0 and where Pin XY will be from that location. You also need to have pre-installed latest Intel Pro-Set Wireless for that card. Usually the driver is just for Wi-Fi but if it's a 100MB package then it has BT drivers too.